# How to plot subfigure in IET template

Tags: floats, subfloats, templates

I have stated my code below. The same code is working with IEEE class file but not working with IET class file. It  is showing error "No counter 'subfigure@save'defined"
Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{IET}%%%%where IET is the template name
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}
\centering
\graphicspath{{},{},{},{}}
\subfloat[x=3]{\includegraphics[width=2.6in,height=2in]{X3}
\label{x3}}
\hfil
\subfloat[x=4]{\includegraphics[width=2.6in,height=2in]{IIX4}
\label{x4}}
\hfil \\
\subfloat[x=5]{\includegraphics[width=2.6in,height=2in]{IIX5}
\label{x5}}
\hfil
\subfloat[x=6]{\includegraphics[width=2.6in,height=2in]{IIX6}
\label{x6}}
\caption{Block}
\label{blocks}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to `IET.cls`?

Comment: http://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/author-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [IET.cls, 2015/11/07 v1.0](http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip) loads the package `subfigure` (without actually using it), which is incompatible with `subfig`. You have two options:

- Rename `IET.cls` to `myIET.cls`, edit the latter file by replacing the line

  ```
  \usepackage{xspace,amscd,rotating,latexsym,multicol,array,algorithm,subfigure}
  ```

  by

  ```
  \usepackage{xspace,amscd,rotating,latexsym,multicol,array,algorithm}
  ```

  and start your document with `\documentclass{myIET}`.
- Don't load the `subfig` package in your document and use the command `\subfigure` instead of `\subfloat` to add captions to your subfigures.